# why pycharm becomes blurred in linux server

Tags: linux, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUCuj.png)

well, I install pycharm in linux, the code font and also the pycharm icon are both blurred, as the picture shows. why? how to fix it? thank you for your answer.

Comment: On your image is a Windows system and it looks like your problem is with PyCharm on Windows

Comment: You are right, it is the window system. I use mobaXterm to connect to the linux server, pycharm installed in linux.

Comment: It could be your xterm client has limited render/display quality, due to network/compression etc.